Dynamically setting graph with type safe Jetpack Compose Navigation
Does navController.setGraph() work in Jetpack Compose type safe navigation?
Calling setGraph sets graph but since NavHost sets navController.graph in either overloads it goes back to initial NavGraph added or built with NavGraphBuilder with a instant flash.

Changing start destination also doesn't change startDestination of graph. Am i missing anything here? I tested with both overloads, still same result. I'm looking for a solution for NavHostController where we check deeplinks and reorder graph accordingly based on deeplink params or if registration is required with accessing NavGraphBuilder or NavGraph with a param but graph from NavHostController.
@Composable
private fun MainContainer() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    // Changing this destination changes where graph will start
    val startDestination = RouteA

    // This NavGraph will be used with NavHost this navHostController will be assigned
    val navGraph: NavGraph = remember(startDestination) {
        navController.createGraph(
            startDestination = startDestination
        ) {
            addNavGraph(navController)
        }
    }

    Column {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
            onClick = {

                navController.setGraph(
                    graph = navController.createGraph(startDestination = RouteC) {
                        addNavGraph(navController)
                    }, startDestinationArgs = null
                )

//                navController.graph.setStartDestination(RouteD)
                println("Start destination: ${navController.graph.startDestinationRoute}")

            }
        ) {
            Text("Set graph")
        }

        /*        NavHost(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    navController = navController,
                    graph = navGraph,
                )
                */

        NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = RouteA
        ) {

            addNavGraph(navController)
        }
    }
}

NavGraphBuilder
private fun NavGraphBuilder.addNavGraph(navController: NavController) {

    composable<RouteA> {
        RouteAScreen(navController)
    }

    composable<RouteB> {
        RouteBScreen(navController)
    }

    composable<RouteC> {
        RouteCScreen(navController)
    }

    composable<RouteD> {
        RouteDScreen(navController)
    }
}

Screens
@Composable
internal fun RouteAScreen(navController: NavController) {
    RouteScreen(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White),
        title = "RouteAScreen",
        navController = navController
    )
}

@Composable
internal fun RouteBScreen(navController: NavController) {
    RouteScreen(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Cyan),
        title = "RouteBScreen",
        navController = navController
    )
}

@Composable
internal fun RouteCScreen(navController: NavController) {
    RouteScreen(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Yellow),
        title = "RouteCScreen",
        navController = navController
    )
}

@Composable
internal fun RouteDScreen(navController: NavController) {
    RouteScreen(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green),
        title = "RouteDScreen",
        navController = navController
    )
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Composable
private fun RouteScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    navController: NavController,
) {

    var popUpToRoute by remember { mutableStateOf<Any?>(null) }

    var popUpToInclusive by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    var isSingleTop by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = title,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )

        ExposedSelectionMenu(title = "PopUpTo",
            index = when (popUpToRoute) {
                null -> 0
                RouteA -> 1
                RouteB -> 2
                RouteC -> 3
                else -> 4
            },
            options = listOf("no popUpTo", "RouteA", "RouteB", "RouteC", "RouteD"),
            onSelected = {
                popUpToRoute = when (it) {
                    0 -> null
                    1 -> RouteA
                    2 -> RouteB
                    3 -> RouteC
                    else -> RouteD
                }
            }
        )

        Row {
            CheckBoxWithText(
                title = "popUpToInclusive",
                enabled = popUpToRoute != null,
                checked = popUpToInclusive
            ) {
                popUpToInclusive = it
            }

            Spacer(Modifier.width(8.dp))

            CheckBoxWithText(
                title = "singleTop",
                checked = isSingleTop
            ) {
                isSingleTop = it
            }
        }

        NavigationButton(
            navController = navController,
            title = "RouteA",
            targetRoute = RouteA,
            popUpToRoute = popUpToRoute,
            popUpToInclusive = popUpToInclusive,
            singleTop = isSingleTop
        )

        NavigationButton(
            navController = navController,
            title = "RouteB",
            targetRoute = RouteB,
            popUpToRoute = popUpToRoute,
            popUpToInclusive = popUpToInclusive,
            singleTop = isSingleTop
        )

        NavigationButton(
            navController = navController,
            title = "RouteC",
            targetRoute = RouteC,
            popUpToRoute = popUpToRoute,
            popUpToInclusive = popUpToInclusive,
            singleTop = isSingleTop
        )

        NavigationButton(
            navController = navController,
            title = "RouteD",
            targetRoute = RouteD,
            popUpToRoute = popUpToRoute,
            popUpToInclusive = popUpToInclusive,
            singleTop = isSingleTop
        )

        val currentBackStack: List<NavBackStackEntry> by navController.currentBackStack.collectAsState()
        val packageName = LocalContext.current.packageName

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {

            // Don't do looped operations in actual code, it's for demonstration
            items(items = currentBackStack.reversed()) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .shadow(4.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline(),
                        text = it.destination.route
                            ?.replace("$packageName.", "")
                            ?.replace(
                                "BottomNavigationRoute.",
                                ""
                            ) ?: it.destination.displayName,
                        fontSize = 16.sp
                    )

                    val text = if (it.destination is NavGraph) "NavGraph" else "NavDestination"

                    Spacer(Modifier.width(4.dp))
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline(),
                        text = "($text)",
                        fontSize = 10.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun NavigationButton(
    navController: NavController,
    title: String,
    targetRoute: Any,
    popUpToRoute: Any? = null,
    popUpToInclusive: Boolean,
    singleTop: Boolean,
) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(
                route = targetRoute
            ) {
                popUpToRoute?.let {
                    popUpTo(
                        route = it
                    ) {
                        inclusive = popUpToInclusive
                    }
                }

                launchSingleTop = singleTop
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text("Navigate to $title")
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CheckBoxWithText(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    checked: Boolean,
    onCheckChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .clickable(
                enabled = enabled
            ) {
                onCheckChange(checked.not())
            }
            .padding(8.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Checkbox(checked = checked, onCheckedChange = null, enabled = enabled)
        Spacer(Modifier.width(16.dp))
        Text(title)
    }
}


You can also consider having graphs in other modules that you can't access directly. In xml in core Module we access graph via NavController.graph and do some changes but i wonder if this is possible with Jetpack Compose navigation

Also since NavHost sets graphs and there is not a proper way to check if graph is set before accessing it throws exception for such a simple thing
